# What's this picture of a smiling character with blue eyes and light hair from?

Tags: touhou-project

[image]

I wonder where is this image from. Does anyone know its origin?

Comment: It seems to be primarily used as somebody's avatar on a number of discussion sites.  Perhaps you could ask them?

Answer (score 10):

I am aware this post is old, but people looking for this same image is going to stumble upon this so I might as well just end the frustrating search.

[Here you go :)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL4yO.jpg)

The picture is from the cover page of [Magicians Don’t Turn Back!](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=92212), a Touhou doujinshi by Saku Saku Tei.

I spent so many hours I don't even want to say how man.

Comment: Very nice find indeed

Answer (score 8):

It's extremely difficult to determine its origin/source. The best I could find is [this image](http://www.giantbomb.com/profile/ihatelolicon/images/), which can be traced back to at least as early as April 10, 2009:

[image: Marisa Kirisame?]

She sure does look like [Marisa Kirisame](http://myanimelist.net/character/5458/Marisa_Kirisame) from the [Touhou Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touhou_Project), even though her eye color in canon is either red (in the PC-95 era) or the more popular yellow. I include two images of Marisa for comparison:

[image: Marisa by Mokku]

<sup>[Original artwork of Marisa](http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=683729) by Mokku (cropped).</sup>

[image: Marisa in Labyrinth of Touhou 2]

<sup>Blue-eyed Marisa in [*Labyrinth of Touhou 2*](http://www.geocities.jp/aaa_3peso/THL2/top.htm), drawn by [Juugoichie](http://eho971.web.fc2.com/).</sup>

Comment: Looking at the [wiki](http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/Marisa_Kirisame) it would be a very close match, they both have a matching braid down one side and the white at the top left corner would be the frills on the inside of her hat

Comment: Yep, quite a close match here: http://en.touhouwiki.net/wiki/File:Th128MarisaKirisame.png (from in the Wiki article)

Comment: Source: http://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=medium&illust_id=17339988